# Extract last non-missing value in row with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table of factor columns, and I want to pull out the label of the last non-missing value in each row.  It's kindof a typical `max.col` situation, but I don't want to needlessly be coercing as I am trying to optimize this code using data.table.  The real data has other types of columns as well.

Here is the example,

```
## Some sample data
set.seed(0)
dat <- sapply(split(letters[1:25], rep.int(1:5, 5)), sample, size=8, replace=TRUE)
dat[upper.tri(dat)] <- NA
dat[4:5, 4:5] <- NA                              # the real data isnt nice and upper.triangular
dat <- data.frame(dat, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)  # factor columns

## So, it looks like this
setDT(dat)[]
#    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1:  u NA NA NA NA
# 2:  f  q NA NA NA
# 3:  f  b  w NA NA
# 4:  k  g  h NA NA
# 5:  u  b  r NA NA
# 6:  f  q  w  x  t
# 7:  u  g  h  i  e
# 8:  u  q  r  n  t

## I just want to get the labels of the factors
## that are 'rightmost' in each row.  I tried a number of things 
## that probably don't make sense here.
## This just about gets the column index
dat[, colInd := sum(!is.na(.SD)), by=1:nrow(dat)]
```

This is the goal though, to extract these labels, here using regular base functions.

```
## Using max.col and a data.frame
df1 <- as.data.frame(dat)
inds <- max.col(is.na(as.matrix(df1)), ties="first")-1
inds[inds==0] <- ncol(df1)
df1[cbind(1:nrow(df1), inds)]
# [1] "u" "q" "w" "h" "r" "t" "e" "t"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
dat[, res := NA_character_]
for (v in rev(names(dat))[-1]) dat[is.na(res), res := get(v)]


   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 res
1:  u NA NA NA NA   u
2:  f  q NA NA NA   q
3:  f  b  w NA NA   w
4:  k  g  h NA NA   h
5:  u  b  r NA NA   r
6:  f  q  w  x  t   t
7:  u  g  h  i  e   e
8:  u  q  r  n  t   t
```

**Benchmarks** Using the same data as @alexis_laz and making (apparently) superficial changes to the functions, I see different results. Just showing them here in case anyone is curious. Alexis' answer (with small modifications) still comes out ahead.

Functions:

```
alex = function(x, ans = rep_len(NA, length(x[[1L]])), wh = seq_len(length(x[[1L]]))){
    if(!length(wh)) return(ans)
    ans[wh] = as.character(x[[length(x)]])[wh]
    Recall(x[-length(x)], ans, wh[is.na(ans[wh])])
}   

alex2 = function(x){
    x[, res := NA_character_]
    wh = x[, .I]
    for (v in (length(x)-1):1){
      if (!length(wh)) break
      set(x, j="res", i=wh, v = x[[v]][wh])
      wh = wh[is.na(x$res[wh])]
    }
    x$res
}

frank = function(x){
    x[, res := NA_character_]
    for(v in rev(names(x))[-1]) x[is.na(res), res := get(v)]
    return(x$res)       
}

frank2 = function(x){
    x[, res := NA_character_]
    for(v in rev(names(x))[-1]) x[is.na(res), res := .SD, .SDcols=v]
    x$res
}
```

Example data and benchmark:

```
DAT1 = as.data.table(lapply(ceiling(seq(0, 1e4, length.out = 1e2)), 
                     function(n) c(rep(NA, n), sample(letters, 3e5 - n, TRUE))))
DAT2 = copy(DAT1)
DAT3 = as.list(copy(DAT1))
DAT4 = copy(DAT1)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(frank(DAT1), frank2(DAT2), alex(DAT3), alex2(DAT4), times = 30)

Unit: milliseconds
         expr       min        lq      mean    median         uq        max neval
  frank(DAT1) 850.05980 909.28314 985.71700 979.84230 1023.57049 1183.37898    30
 frank2(DAT2)  88.68229  93.40476 118.27959 107.69190  121.60257  346.48264    30
   alex(DAT3)  98.56861 109.36653 131.21195 131.20760  149.99347  183.43918    30
  alex2(DAT4)  26.14104  26.45840  30.79294  26.67951   31.24136   50.66723    30
```

Answer (score 11):

Another idea -similar to Frank's- that tries (1) to avoid subsetting 'data.table' rows (which I assume must have some cost) and (2) to avoid checking a `length == nrow(dat)` vector for `NA`s in every iteration.

```
alex = function(x, ans = rep_len(NA, length(x[[1L]])), wh = seq_len(length(x[[1L]])))
{
    if(!length(wh)) return(ans)
    ans[wh] = as.character(x[[length(x)]])[wh]
    Recall(x[-length(x)], ans, wh[is.na(ans[wh])])
}   
alex(as.list(dat)) #had some trouble with 'data.table' subsetting
# [1] "u" "q" "w" "h" "r" "t" "e" "t"
```

And to compare with Frank's:

```
frank = function(x)
{
    x[, res := NA_character_]
    for(v in rev(names(x))[-1]) x[is.na(res), res := get(v)]
    return(x$res)       
}

DAT1 = as.data.table(lapply(ceiling(seq(0, 1e4, length.out = 1e2)), 
                     function(n) c(rep(NA, n), sample(letters, 3e5 - n, TRUE))))
DAT2 = copy(DAT1)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(alex(as.list(DAT1)), 
                               { frank(DAT2); DAT2[, res := NULL] }, 
                               times = 30)
#Unit: milliseconds
#                                            expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#                             alex(as.list(DAT1))  102.9767  108.5134  117.6595  133.1849  166.9594    30
# {     frank(DAT2)     DAT2[, `:=`(res, NULL)] } 1413.3296 1455.1553 1497.3517 1540.8705 1685.0589    30
identical(alex(as.list(DAT1)), frank(DAT2))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Yeah, I got my idea from one of your earlier posts. I wonder how it compares against `dat[, colInd := Reduce(function(x,y) x+!is.na(y), .SD, init=0L)][, res := as.character(.SD[[.BY[[1]]]]), by=colInd]`. For few cols and many rows, I think this way might be pretty good. Also, the OP's `max.col` approach would be interesting to see.

Comment: @Frank : With a rough benchmark, `Reduce..` is indeed faster than your first approach, but, I guess, the triple reading each column for `+`, `!` and `is.na` adds some time. I didn't add the `max.col`, because `microbenchmark(as.matrix(DAT1))` seems slow enough to begin with.

Comment: @TheTime : Did you use a "data.table" in the recursive function? I had some trouble with 'data.table' subsetting and used `as.list.data.table` first.

Comment: I was having the same issue as TheTime, but `as.list` resolved it, yeah.

Comment: Oh, I know why it fails with a data.table -- `x[-length(x)]` doesn't work the same way.

Comment: @TheTime : Was, just, thinking that a `for(i in length(x):1)` might avoid the iterative subsetting of "x" but was a bit cleaner to update the indices of non-`NA`s with recursion. @Frank : I, also, tried `x[, -length(x), with = FALSE]` but, still, had some problems with the function

Comment: Added another benchmark with your idea but in a loop with `set`; it's somewhat faster.

Answer (score 4):

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' and create a row id column  (`setDT(df1, keep.rownames=TRUE)`).  We reshape the 'wide' to 'long' format with `melt`.  Grouped by 'rn', `if` there is no `NA` element in 'value' column, we get the last element of 'value' (`value[.N]`) or `else`, we get the element before the first NA in the 'value' to get the 'V1' column, which we extract (`$V1`).

```
melt(setDT(df1, keep.rownames=TRUE), id.var='rn')[,
     if(!any(is.na(value))) value[.N] 
     else value[which(is.na(value))[1]-1], by =  rn]$V1
#[1] "u" "q" "w" "h" "r" "t" "e" "t"
```

In case, the data is already a `data.table`

```
dat[, rn := 1:.N]#create the 'rn' column
melt(dat, id.var='rn')[, #melt from wide to long format
     if(!any(is.na(value))) value[.N] 
     else value[which(is.na(value))[1]-1], by =  rn]$V1
#[1] "u" "q" "w" "h" "r" "t" "e" "t"
```

Here is another option

```
dat[, colInd := sum(!is.na(.SD)), by=1:nrow(dat)][
   , as.character(.SD[[.BY[[1]]]]), by=colInd]
```

Or as @Frank mentioned in the comments, we can use `na.rm=TRUE` from `melt` and make it more compact

```
 melt(dat[, r := .I], id="r", na.rm=TRUE)[, value[.N], by=r]
```

Comment: @TheTime Yes, you can do it like that, but if we have to convert from `data.frame` to `data.table`, the options in `setDT` will be handy.

Comment: @TheTime Sorry for that, I added some explanations.  The `value` is from the default column names after the `melt` step.

Comment: @TheTime Another option would be using `pmax` after converting to `character` columns., though it is kind of tricky here.  I have to go now, will try it later.

Comment: Here's something ridiculous I came up with. I doubt it's worthy of an answer though: `dat[, do.call(Map, c(function(...) tail(c(...)[!is.na(c(...))],1), lapply(dat,as.character)) )]`

Comment: You can drop NAs in the melt: `melt(dat[, r := .I], id="r", na.rm=TRUE)[, value[.N], by=r]`

Comment: @TheTime You mentioned that "This operation is going to be happening many times in real-time setting." That is probably the root of the problem and it sounds like something avoidable.

Comment: @TheTime You could benchmark all these options.  The `data.table` `melt` is fast though I haven't benchmarked all these.

Comment: @TheTime Your .BY option is probably slow because you do a by-row operation before it. Instead... `dat[, colInd := Reduce(function(x,y) x+!is.na(y), .SD, init=0L)][, res := as.character(.SD[[.BY[[1]]]]), by=colInd]` (Not sure if you want to change it.)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one liner `base R` approach:

```
sapply(split(dat, seq(nrow(dat))), function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)],1))
#  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
#"u" "q" "w" "h" "r" "t" "e" "t"
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how to improve upon @alexis's answer beyond what @Frank has already done, but your original approach with base R wasn't too far off of something that is reasonably performant.

Here's a variant of your approach that I liked because (1) it's reasonably quick and (2) it doesn't require too much thought to figure out what's going on:

```
as.matrix(dat)[cbind(1:nrow(dat), max.col(!is.na(dat), "last"))]
```

The most expensive part of this seems to be the `as.matrix(dat)` part, but otherwise, it seems to be faster than the `melt` approach that @akrun shared.