# Multiple observations per ID, create column for last observation

Tags: r, multiple-columns, missing-data

I have data where each row can have up to 3 observations of a measurement.  I'm trying to create a column that pulls just the last observation.

For example, my data looks like:

```
Participant  x1  x2  x3
1            10  NA  NA 
2            5   15  NA
3            5   20  30
4            20  NA  NA
```

And I'm trying to get this:

```
Participant  x1  x2  x3  x_final
1            10  NA  NA  10
2            5   15  NA  15
3            5   20  30  30
4            20  NA  NA  20
```

How should I go about this?  I'm a bit new to R and haven't been able to figure it out from searching for other examples.

Comment: Try `df1$x_final <- df1[cbind(1:nrow(df1), max.col(!is.na(df1), "last"))]; df1$x_final#[1] 10 15 30 20`

Comment: Related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664659/extract-last-non-missing-value-in-row-with-data-table